# How can I put data directly in the blobstore?

Tags: java, blobstore

Please, does anyone knows how can I upload data directly to the blobstore, I mean, data coming from an urlfetch or an e-mail atachment?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like the blobstore catches/processes requests *before* they reach the general app-engine cluster. So the only way to add data into the blobstore is via an HTTP multipart POST.

If you are intending on adding something to the blobstore while you are already within your application you are more than likely going to hit the 30second request timeout.

If your data is [smaller than 1MB](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits), then you should just use the [blob properties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobProperty).
If it is larger than 1MB then you will have to change your approach.

Comment: It's just what I though, the quotas limitations in appengine are very restrictive..., I have been implementing approaches to problems with solutions that are far from something realistic in any other environment, anyway, thanks.